# Discord.js music bot having issue at coding

Tags: discord.js

I am almost sure I am getting this error because of the brackets but I haven't been able to solve it. I am trying to make a *discord bot* that plays music:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const PREFIX = '';
    const ydtl = require("ytdl-core")
    const Token = "(token here)";
    var servers = {}
    
        client.on('message', message =>{
            console.log("ESTOU ONLINE CARALHO");
            let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
            
         
            switch (args[0]) {
                 
                case 'play':
    
                    function play(connection, message){
    
                        var server = servers[message.guild.id];
                        server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
    
                        server.queue.shift();             
                        
                        server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                            if(server.queue[0]){
                                play(connection,message);
                            }else {connection.disconnect()};
                            
    
                        });
                     }
    
                    if(!args[1]){
                        message.channel.send("Tens que por o link da musica CARALHO");
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    if(!message.member.voiceChannel){
                        message.channel.send("precisas de estar num canal de voz pra fazeres isso OH BURRO");
                        return;
                    }
    
                    if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                        queue:[]
                    }
    
                    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    
                    server.queue.push(args[1])
    
                    if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
    
                        play(connection, message);
                    })
                    break;
            
                }
```

I am getting an error here: `client.login(Token);`. Why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please view the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). We need to be provided with errors and specific issues before reviewing your code. Thanks!

Comment: Also you should remove your token from the code....

Comment: You should *regenerate your token immediately*. Anyone with enough reputation can still see older revisions of your question, even if you edit it out (though I agree with @Landon that you should edit it out).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t seem you logged in to the API in the code you provided, try adding`client.login(Token);` at the end of the file.